# Best location for installing or upgrading NodeJS

Tags: node.js, frameworks

I am just about to upgrade my current version 3.8.7 of NodeJS to Node 4.5.0 LTS but thought I might quickly check my previously set execution path:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
```

I am thinking the Windows installer will use the second path. However, I must of previously installed using a command line with the -g or global option, to get the install in the second path Is this best location or approach if I need to have other versions of Node installed and switch between them?  What is everyone else doing ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I got confused with Node and npm, it is the latter, I install globally

For 4.5.4 ( under C:\Program Files\Nodejs)

```
choco install nodejs.install -version 4.4.6
```

for npm ( under C:\Users\Daniel\appdata)

```
npm -g install npm@next
```

hope this deconfuses someone ;-)